# Cannot activate automatic login

Tags: boot, password

This function is kinda useless on local PC, and on windows it's easily done, how do I do it on Ubuntu?

1. I went to **settings->users->unlock->automatic** login switched on. But as soon as I close that window, all settings are coming back where they were, it's like there has to be a button "save changes" but there isn't
2. When it did not help I did
3. `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` Changed the line `#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false` then saved changes. Didn't work either

**Dont' know how, but situation resolved by itself. Did nothing new.**

Comment: 1. i went to settings, activated autologin
2. did
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
Changed the line
#WaylandEnable=false
to
WaylandEnable=false
and it comes back after restart and asks password again every boot

Comment: Did you change anything compared to the default installation? Because the "autologin" option usually does what is advertised...

Comment: yeah, i went to settings->users->unlock->automatic login switched on. 
but as soon as i close that window, all settings are coming back where they were, it's like there has to be a button "save changes" but there isn't

Comment: I changed the Topic of the question... because it will get closed if you ask for password less login.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, I run Settings and then select 'Users'.  The 'automatic login' option is found there.